# Is it possible to make WebApI project and MVC project work in same port

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a MVC 4.0 project. The structure looks like this.

```
MySolution   
   BLL
   DAL
   MyProj
   MyAPIProj
```

`DAL` contains the `.edmx`.
`BLL` contains the services that talk with `DAL` and Models to retain the data.
`MyProj`  has controllers and views. Also, it has reference to the DAL and BLL.

All the above mentioned projects are under one solution.

Now the requirement is :  we are trying to create a new layer of abstraction using Web API.  Instead of the controllers in `MyProj` talking to the `BLL` we want to create a WebAPI and `Myproj` will call the `WebApi`  and after basic validation the `WebApi` will talk to the `BLL` and based on the input received by the `BLL` the response will be sent back to the `WebAPI` and then to `MYProj`.

Now from `MyProj` I am making an .ajax call to `MYAPIProj` and in `MYAPIProj` i have reference to the BLL and DAL. My question is
I need both applications to use the same port. Is there a way to do that in Visual Studio?
If not, what would be the best way to make it work locally.

Comment: You cannot have two applications listen on the same port on the same IP at the same time. You might be able to use IIS configurations to have them run under different virtual directories though.

Comment: Web API and MVC can use same port only if you host them as a same project which does not suit your solution architecture. If you build them as two distinct projects, then what DigitalID wrote is unfortunately true.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Host Headers in IIS (locally and on the server) and do something like:

```
app.mydomain.com
api.mydomain.com
```

Host Headers in IIS 7: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195(v=ws.10).aspx

Or you can create the API as an application within your main app so it would look like:

```
api.mydomain.com/service/ (where service is the application)
```